# Tomcat Active Session not aligned to Total Active Connection Count on LoadBalancer

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jsessionid

In preparation to performance test a java servlet application deployed on Tomcat. We have total of 18 servers, loadbalanced on a roundrobin mechanism.  Analysing the current prod usage, I see the tomcat active session/per day  at about 9K session on average per node and total across the group X 18 = 162 sessions (please see Tomcat Active Session Graph below)

The peak total request on the load balancer/per hour for the same period is around 3M (please see the Load Balancer Total Request Count/per Hour graph). Based on the 3M total request the total active session seem comparable.

Does that imply a new session is created for each incoming request and not reusing the exitsing TCP connection established? Total Active connection count on the AWS load balancer/hour for the same period is around 40K.  (The total number of concurrent TCP connections active from clients to the load balancer and from the load balancer to targets)

Typical user will have to login to the application and perform request. The session timeout on the application is set to 60 minutes.

Tomcat Active Session Graph (aggregated hourly)

[image]

Load Balancer Total Request Count/Hour
[image]

LBTotalActiveConnection/Hour
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem... (Is it that you think the number of active sessions is disproportionate to the number of requests?) Also, isn't 60K the maximum number or requests per minute, not the total requests per day?

Comment: @Nikos, thats correct. I thought the number of active session is disproportinate to the number of  requests, but just realized after your post that number of requests I have been looking are per minute and hourly sum come to 3M requests. Based on this the total active session for the combined servers is 3M/18 servers = 166K, is what we are seeing. Does that mean or rather clear that a new active session is being created for each request.

Comment: I also looked at the active connection count (The total number of concurrent TCP connections active from clients to the load balancer and from the load balancer to targets )on the load balancer per hour and  peak observed is around 40K.

Comment: @Nikos- I have edited my orginal question accordingly based on my revised analysis. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm it might be late here and there are numbers and graphs :) But did you do 9K on average per node **x** 18 nodes = 162K sessions **total**, while doing 3M total requests **/** 18 nodes = 166K requests **per node**? Shouldn't you compare 3M requests to 162K sessions total (which looks prety OK)?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. Yes comparing 3M request to 162K session looks pretty ok, but it more on a 1:1 ratio. My understanding is that a tomcat session will be established on user login and the same session will be used to serve the multiple request from the user until before the user logsout or the session expires after idle timout of 60 minutes.

Comment: The  total ActiveConnectionCount/Hour on LoadBalancer was around 40K for the same period (I thought this might be a better comparison to active tomcat sessions), which on comparison to the tomcat active session seem very dispropotianate

Comment: Does your application **always** use sessions? Not all authentication methods require sessions.

Comment: @Piotr - As I understand, the application always use sessions. Also, there is a new world application to this running in parallel, where some users are already migrated and have the provision to switch between old and new as some funtionality are yet to be migrated to new world application. Redis session cache is used to maintain the  user sessions across both the application. The new wolrd application on every user interation send a ping to the old world application to keep the session alive on the old application.